# Proving a subset is an ideal in Q[x,y]

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

I am tasked to prove that the subset:

$K:= \{P\in \mathbb{Q}[x,y]|P(1,0)=P(0,3)=0\}$

is an ideal in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$.

Now I understand the steps to show a subset is an ideal but I'm not sure how to apply them or how to interpret K.

Firstly, is K representing the ideal $\langle x,3y \rangle$?

Am I correct in thinking I need to test if $P +Q \in K$ for $P,Q \in k$
and if $PQ \in K$ for $P \in K$ and $Q \in \mathbb{Q}[x,y]$? I'm very confused as to find out how to complete these calculations.

Any advise is greatly appreciated, I want to complete these equations myself but the lecture notes I am following are really not very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think $K$ is $\langle x, 3y\rangle$. For example, does $x$ actually vanish at $(1,0)$? But don't worry about this for now...

Comment: Ask yourself: if $P$ and $Q$ are two polynomials that vanish at $(1,0)$, then what must be the value of $P+Q$ at $(1,0)$?

Comment: I think the value of $P + Q$ must be $0$ at $(1,0$ or $(0,3)$.

Comment: Yes. So if $P$ and $Q$ are in $K$, does $P+Q$ necessarily have to be in $K$?

Comment: So to mirror the one example I have, I guess that $(P+Q)[1,0] = P[1,0] + Q[1,0] = 0 + 0 = 0$ and likewise for  $(0,3)$

Comment: and then in this context, $P+Q$ is in $K$

Comment: Good. Now suppose $P$ is in $K$ and $Q$ is anything. Is $PQ$ then in $K$?

Comment: $(PQ)[1,0]=P[1,0]Q[1,0]=0*Q[1,0]=0$ which is again in $K$ and likewise for $[0,3]$

Comment: so then $Q \in K$. Does this satisfy as proof it is an ideal?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the ring $R\triangleq\mathbb Q [x,y]$ is commutative, in order to show $K\triangleleft R$ one must show the following:
1. $K\neq\emptyset$ 
2. $\forall a,b\in K \implies a+b\in K$ 
3. $\forall a\in K \implies (-a)\in K$ 
4. $\forall a\in K,r\in R \implies ar\in K$ 
Showing that $K\neq \emptyset$ is easy. 
Now, consider $a,b\in K$. This means $a=P(x,y) \in \mathbb Q[x,y]$ such that $P(1,0)=P(0,3)=0$. Same can be written about $b=S(x,y) \in \mathbb Q[x,y]$ such that $S(1,0)=S(0,3)=0$. By definition  $a+b =P(x,y)+S(x,y)$ implying that $a+b\in K$ because $P(1,0)+S(1,0)=P(0,3)+S(0,3)=0+0=0$. 
In the same way you can prove the third condition. 
The last one is usually the condition that defines the ideal. Consider $r=P(x,y)\in \mathbb Q[x,y]$ being any polynomial and let $a=S(x,y) \in K $ therefore $S(1,0)=S(0,3)=0$. Also by definition $ar=S(x,y)\cdot P(x,y)$ and one can argue that $S(1,0)\cdot P(1,0) = 0 \cdot P(1,0) = 0 = 0 \cdot P(0,3) = S(0,3) \cdot P(0,3)$. From this you can conclude that $ar\in K$ and therefore $K\triangleleft R$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those are the steps to do in order to show $K$ is an ideal.

If $P,Q\in K$ and $R=P+Q$, then
$$
R(1,0)=P(1,0)+Q(1,0)=0,
\qquad
R(0,3)=P(0,3)+Q(0,3)=0
$$
Similarly if $P\in K$ and $Q\in\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$.

Note that $x\notin K$ and $3y\notin K$. What you should consider are $x-1$ and $y-3$, but they aren't in $K$, so some adjustments are to be made. Hint: use the fact that, for any polynomial $P(x,y)\in\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ you can write
\begin{align}
P(x,y)&=(x-1)Q_1(x,y)+R_1(y)\\
&=(y-3)Q_2(x,y)+R_2(x)
\end{align}

Comment: It's not true that $K = (x-1, y-3)$, is it?  It seems to me that $K = (x-1,y) \cap (x, y-3) = (x-1,y) (x,y-3) = (x(x-1), xy, (x-1)(y-3),y(y-3))$.

Comment: @SpamIAm Thanks, I changed the hint